# Creating MVC controller in Javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm doing my first Javascript project using a MVC. However I have hit a small snag when it comes to how to build the Control. Here is a simplified example:

```
// This is the Model
var Classroom = function() {

    this.students = Array();

};

Classroom.prototype.addStudent = function( name ) {

    this.students.push( name );

};

// This is the Controller
var ClassroomFromCsv = function() {};

ClassroomFromCsv.prototype.make =  function( csv ) {

    var classroom = new Classroom();

    var names = csv.split( ',' );

    for( var i = 0; i < names.length; i++ ) {

        classroom.addStudent( names[i] );

    }

    return classroom;

};

// Create instance of controller
var classroomFromCsvController = new ClassroomFromCsv();

// Using the controller
var myClassroom = classroomFromCsvController.make( 'Jim,Bob,Sam,Greg' );
```

By its very nature a controller does not seem to work in an object oriented methodology. It doesn't need to hold data. It just takes data, manipulates it and then passes it to an Model or View. Instantiating and having the option of instantiating multiple seems clumsy and unnecessary.

- I could make the controller a global function, but is this a good practice in object oriented programming?
- I could add the controller as a prototype to the Model, but then its not really MVC is it?
- I could make the controller a singleton object and make static calls to the make method, but I have heard nothing but negativity about singletons from purists.

What are the best/most common practices for controllers in Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: http://todomvc.com/  take a look into this

Comment: Oh boy, I'm not sure you understand MVC very well yet. Here is a great article to get you started :) http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

Comment: Also, singletons are horrible not just from a purist point of view, they're an implicit global variable used for global state. Adding the controller to the model is not MVC but then again you're not doing anything with UI here really so no MVC to begin with. Globals are bad but have nothing to do with the MVC architectural pattern. My suggestion is to learn about SOLID and good coding practices and worry less about specific architectural patterns.

Comment: Ok... Thanks... Not really the response I was expecting. I am trying to follow SOLID coding practices which is why I have found myself trying this pattern. And considering this is just a simplified example in which I have left off any UI... But confessing I am new to MVC I am happy for constructive feedback. So what would you do and what concepts do you think I am missing?